# Dynamic import() fails in webapack

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I want to import jQuery dynamically so that webpack can emit it as a chunk but when I use dynamic import like this:

```
import ('../vendorjs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js').then($ => {
    (function() {
        $('.tabs').tabs();
    })
});
```

this file is imported in an entry file :

```
//other imports
import './materialize.init';
```

But when I run webapck, I get this error stack

> ERROR in ./src/js/materialize.init.js 1:7
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   import ('../vendorjs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js').then($ => {
>      (function() {
>    |         $('.tabs').tabs();
>   @ ./src/js/index.js 9:0-28

Comment: You should rather `import $ from "jquery";` and then tell webpack that it is an external

Comment: Thanks for that, i have found out that the problem  is with vscode studion insreting spaces around the import('x') ==> import ('x').